# Android: Multiple Dimensional array - java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I've got an array coming in from a cursor in a function from a sqlite database. I'd like to add multiple items to the array to make it easier to bring data in from other pages. I.e. I'd like to do mArray("ID"), mArray("Name") (i'll be populating a listview from an array of the function, and would like to have easy access to name from ID)

Here is my code at the moment which only saves the ID in the array:

```
public static Array GetRooms(String StationID) {

    File dbfile = new File(Global.currentDBfull); 
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from StationObjects where ObjectID = 0 and StationID = " + StationID , null);  

       c.moveToFirst();
       Log.e("TomDebug", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SubGroupName")));

     ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
       c.moveToFirst();
       while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
            mArrayList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SubGroupName")));
            c.moveToNext();
       }


    return null;

}
```

Edit: To give a bit of clarity;

In psudocode i'd like to be able to do:

```
 while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
            mArrayList.name.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name")));
            mArrayList.type.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Type")));
            mArrayList.ID.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ID")));
            c.moveToNext();
       }
```

So that anywhere in the code i can do

```
Array curRooms = GetRooms("1234")

String name = curRooms.Name
String type = curRooms.Type
```

(i know the mix between array and string wont work there, but just an example)

Comment: Can you give an example? It's not clear how this data structure is supposed to work...

Comment: Added a bit more infor for you

Comment: Why not create a custom object that will hold the desired fields?

Comment: I guess you could use an ORM framework. Have a look at ormlite: http://ormlite.com/. The creator sometimes lurks around SO.

Comment: Your last example is consistant with an approach where you have a single List (or array) of Objects with Name, Type and Id class member fields.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an actual data structure instead of a string.  There are a few ways of doing this, with ORMs and whatnot, but a basic example would be something like this, that you can fill the fields in from the database.

```
public class StationObject
{
  public String name;
  public String type;
  public String id;
}

//pseudocode
for each result in resultset
  fill temp StationObject with fields
  add temp to list
```